# How to recognize which calendar the event belongs in Microsoft graph api?

Tags: azure, events, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing application that synchronize with microsoft calendar.
To get any changes on Microsoft calendar I use webHook service and every time receive new/deleted/updated events but I do not know which calendar the event belongs, even after I get full event from Microsoft and not only the ID.

There are many calendars for user! 
How can I recognize id of calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [event resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) has a `calendar` relationship, so that you should be able to do:

```
GET /me/events/{event-id}/calendar
```

Comment: This works for me with events from my own calendar only. Anyone please be cautious when working with group calendars, shared calendars or special calendars - the ms graph api returns an invalid calendar entity for the event relation on request. I hope this will help someone when having the same trouble as I did when running into this issue. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444486/microsoft-graph-api-beta-retrieving-calendar-for-event-returns-unexpected-cale